# Chrome Extension: unable to display buttons in popup when storage has correct information

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

For my Chrome extension, I am storing tab information such as the name of the tab, URL of the tab, etc, and then putting all of it into storage. In my popup, I display buttons that are able to create those tabs, and have a button counter to keep track of the number of buttons.

When I delete a button, the storage updates correctly, but I am unable to display the correct number of buttons. For example, if there are 4 buttons and I delete the first button, only 2 buttons will be displayed in the popup.

- groupCount: number of buttons (not including "trash" buttons)
- the number after tabNames, tabUrls, tabCount (ex: tabNames1) refers to which button it is a part of, with button numbers starting at 0

## console.log after making all 4 buttons:

```
// after displaying all the buttons, storage: groupCount,groupName0,groupName1,groupName2,groupName3,
   //tabCount0,tabCount1,tabCount2,tabCount3,tabNames0,tabNames1,tabNames2,tabNames3,tabUrls0,tabUrls1,
   //tabUrls2,tabUrls3
// popup.js:34 after displaying all the buttons, groupCount: 4
```

## console.log after deleting the first button

```
// after displaying all the buttons, storage: groupCount,groupName1,groupName2,groupName3,
   //tabCount1,tabCount2,tabCount3,tabNames1,tabNames2,tabNames3,tabUrls1,tabUrls2,tabUrls3
// popup.js:34 after displaying all the buttons, groupCount: 3
```

## popup.js

```
// calls function to populate buttons for popup
insertButtons();

/* Inserts buttons into popup */
function insertButtons()
{
    var groupCount;

    chrome.storage.local.get("groupCount", function(group)
    {
        groupCount = group.groupCount;

        /* checks if there are no buttons */
        if (groupCount == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("groupButtons").innerHTML = "Empty!";
            document.getElementById("groupButtons").style.color = "blue";
            document.getElementById("groupButtons").style.fontWeight = "900";
        }
        /* creates the buttons */
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < groupCount; i++)
            {
                getStorage(i);
            }

            /* debugging */
            chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) 
            {
                var allKeys = Object.keys(items);
                console.log("after displaying all the buttons, storage: " + allKeys);
            });
            chrome.storage.local.get("groupCount", function(groups)
            {
                console.log("after displaying all the buttons, groupCount: " + groups.groupCount);
            })
        }
    })
}

function getStorage(i)   // i == groupCount
{
    chrome.storage.local.get(["groupName" + i, "tabCount" + i, "tabUrls" + i], function(group)
    {
        /* checks  if storage is empty or if a group was deleted */
        if (group["groupName" + i] == null)
        {
            console.log("empty");
            return;
        }

        /* tab button */
        var groupButton = document.createElement("button");
        /* set css of button */
        groupButton.type = "button";
        groupButton.innerHTML = group["groupName" + i];   // displays name of the button
        // puts button in popup
        document.getElementById("groupButtons").appendChild(groupButton);

        /* opens tabs if button is clicked */
        groupButton.onclick = function()
        {
            /* opens the tabs */
            for (var j = 0; j < group["tabCount" + i]; j++)
            {
                chrome.tabs.create({"url": group["tabUrls" + i][j], "active": false});   // opens url of tab in the group
            }
        }

        /* trash button */
        var trashButton = document.createElement("button");
        //trashButton.type = "trashButton";
        trashButton.innerHTML = "Trash";
        // appends button to corresponding tab button
        document.getElementById("groupButtons").appendChild(trashButton);

        /* deletes group if trash icon is clicked  */
        trashButton.onclick = function()
        {
            var confirmDelete = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected categories?\n\n");
            if (confirmDelete)
            {
                // removes the group name, tab names, tab urls, and number of tabs from storage
                chrome.storage.local.remove(["groupName" + i, "tabNames" + i, "tabUrls" + i, "tabCount" + i]);

                chrome.storage.local.get("groupCount", function(group)
                {
                    var resetGroupCount = group.groupCount - 1;
                    // subtract one from groupCount for removal of a group
                    chrome.storage.local.set({"groupCount": resetGroupCount});
                })
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving `window.location.reload();` into a callback for updating groupCount:

```
            chrome.storage.local.get("groupCount", function(group)
            {
                var resetGroupCount = group.groupCount - 1;
                // subtract one from groupCount for removal of a group
                chrome.storage.local.set({"groupCount": resetGroupCount}, function(s){
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            })
```

Comment: I've managed to bypass the problem by creating a new storage variable that would store the total number of buttons. The problem was that when I deleted, say the first button, groupCount would not be able to iterate to the last button in the for loop with getStorage(i) because groupCount would be 3, and the button information would be 3 while the loop goes until < groupCount.

Comment: I've made it so the new storage variable (buttonCounter) would reset to 0 if there are no buttons, but now the problem is that it will keep increasing if the user never deletes all of the buttons. Would this affect the chrome extension's functionality, or would it have a negligible effect?

Comment: Ah. Now I think I get it. So you have a bunch of variables called groupName1/groupName2/etc, and when you delete one of them (say groupName2) it just skips so it's like groupName1/groupName3/etc. Then because groupCount is set to 2, it causes an error because it looks for groupName1 & groupName2, but it's not groupName2, it should be groupName3. Is this right?

Sorry for my quick answer, I thought it was errors to do with your handling of asynchronous functions but it's more of a logic problem.

Comment: What would happen if you used arrays? aka an array of objects, where each object has tabNames & tabUrls, and then using for loops it should show every button. You wouldn't need to keep track of how many buttons there are, you just use .length on the array. e.g. store `tabList = [{tabNames:[/*tabnames*/], tabUrls:[/*taburls*/]}]`